# Finding eigenvectors of the rotation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta &\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{C})$

I've got the eigenvalues of

Therefore $\lambda=\cos\left(\theta\right)+\sqrt{\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)-1}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$

and

$\lambda=\cos\left(\theta\right)-\sqrt{\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)-1}=\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)=e^{-i\theta}$

I'm finding the eigenvector for one of them by computing

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
\cos\theta-e^{i\theta} & \sin\theta & 0\\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta-e^{i\theta} & 0
\end{array}\right]$

but I cannot seem to find an a basis for such a kernel? Any tips?

Comment: Keep using Euler's formula with that matrix

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I've been trying for a while.. could you help me:?

Comment: $\cos\theta - (\cos\theta + i \sin \theta) = - i \sin\theta$ ...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, writing the eigenvalues in the condensed form $e^{\pm i \theta}$ is not helpful.

Consider the eigenvalue $\lambda = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$. We must compute the kernel of
$$
A - \lambda I = \pmatrix{- i \sin \theta & \sin \theta\\ -\sin \theta & -i \sin \theta} = \sin \theta \cdot \pmatrix{-i & 1\\-1 & -i}.
$$
Perhaps the way forward is a bit clearer now.

Comment: im still not sure.. could you help? i keep getting a full number of pivots in RREF form

Comment: @expl0it3r You're probably multiplying something incorrectly. Note that the second row is $-i$ multiplied by the first row.